# Nextcloud online account - difference between files and documents

Tags: 19.04, online-accounts, nextcloud

I am wondering what the difference is between the **Documents** option and **Files** option for a Nextcloud Ubuntu online account.

- The **Files** one seem to add a dav shortcut to my file explorer. If I disable Files, the dav shortcut goes away.
- When I enable / disable **Documents**, I see no obvious changes.

Neither one seems to actually sync files - I had to install a desktop client for that.

[image]